# How to edit subform based on joined tables in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, join, ms-access-2010

I'm designing an Access 2010 web database, and I'm trying to create a subform that will display data based on joined tables. It displays alright, but I can't modify the data. The two tables are called Consortiums and PrincipleInvestigators. There's a many-to-many link between them, so I have a ConsortiumsPrincipleInvestigators join table.

I have a "consortium" form which displays the data related to a specific consortium, and has a subform within that form that displays the principle investigators part that consortium. I was able to successfully all the PIs, but when I try to add a principle investigator within that subform, it gives me an error: "Cannot add record(s); join key of table 'PrincipleInvestigatorsConsortiums' not in recordset. What gives? I imagine it's because I need to update both the PrincipleInvestigators table and the join table. (Also, MS, why can't I just use standard relational database stuff instead of this silly lookup field business?) Here's some screenshots of my table layout and my join table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hW3Y.png

Bleh. I feel noobish although I've done a decent amount of database projects, but the lookup fields and query builder is throwing me off. Does anyone know of any good tutorials on how to design queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really nothing that changes in terms of building a relationship between two tables. The fact that you use a GUI, a SQL DLL command, or now some relationship wizard changes nothing.

I mean who cares what the process is much to setup a relationship between two tables?

I mean, in client based you could type in something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Cars
   ADD CONSTRAINT MyColorIDRelationship
   FOREIGN KEY (ColorID) REFERENCES Colors (ColorID)
```

So, now you use some wizard that is a few mouse clicks and this is some big deal? Really, who cares! No big woopy here, all we care is that you execute some command, or some wizard, or something here and you at the end of your day the result is your beloved relation between the two tables.

Check out the following video of mine where I "hook up" some existing related data into a web database. And I ALSO share how you can printout the related tables using the Access relationship window for a web database:

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL27E956A1537FE1C5&feature=plcp

So, at the end of the day, no need to get twisted up in some details of having to use some DDL sql command, some GUI relationships window, or some wizard. All you are doing as the above video shows is hooking up some tables and setting up a relation – nothing more, nothing less to worry about.

As for how to add child records that are to be related to a parent record? Well, in the past for the last 18 years, quite much every bird, dog, and beetle using Access would simply do this:

a) Create a main form based on the ONE main parent record table. There is NO NEED to build a query here, and in fact NO need to build a query that is a join of the two tables – this was never required and is not required. All you do is build a form based on the one simple table. We are done this part "a".

b) Create a form based on the ONE child table. There is NO NEED TO build a query here, and in fact NO need to build a query that is a join of the two tables – this was never required and is not required. All you do is build a form based on the one simple table.

c) open up first form (the form based on parent record table) and then in layout mode, now drag + drop in the child form from the nav pane.

The above a,b,c steps is how virtually EVERY parent to child setup in Access I seen done, and this long time forever setup CONTINUES to work 100% in web based applications.

In both cases (web or non web), the setup remains the same, the setup does not involve building quires, and the setup does not require ANY coding on your part.

As long as the link/master child settings are correct in the sub form control, then you are free to add child records to the child form and Access will do the rest of the dirty work of setting up and  maintain the relation for you by setting the FK column in that child form for you.

So, how the basic setup works here has not changed in 18 years of using Access, and as such this does not change when building a web form here.

You don't need a query based on more than one table, and in fact JUST like in the past, the two forms will as a general rule will have their data source based only on the one table.

So in most cases there was never a need to even use a query for that one table that the form is going to be based on. This long time basic approach and setup has not change for web forms either.

In your case I would assume the main form is Consortium. You child form could be a continues form based on Principleinvegiartors. And in place of having to manually enter some PrincipleInvetigaor ID, you use a combo box based on table PrincipleInvetgioars. However, again in all cases, we are simply building forms that are based on a single base table.

Answer (score 0):

For this situation, you should choose one of your tables for the main form and the junction table for the subform.

For example:

```
Main Table
Consortiums 

Subform
ConsortiumsPrincipleInvestigators 

Link Child and Master Fields ConsortiumID

ComboBox on subform
Principal investors
Row source: SELECT InvestorID, InvestorDetails FROM PrincipalInvestors
Control Source: InvestorID
Bound Column: 1
Column Count: 2
Column Widths: 0,2
```

Some notes on Not In List

```
        DoCmd.OpenForm "AddSomething", , , , , acDialog, AddData

        If Forms!AddSomething.Tag <> "" Then
            frm(cbo).Undo
            frm(cbo).Requery
            frm(cbo) = Forms!AddSomething.Tag

            AddCombo = acDataErrAdded
        Else
            AddCombo = acDataErrContinue
        End If

        DoCmd.Close acForm, "AddSomething"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm currently trying to use the subform wizard, and simply adding fields from the PrincipleInvestigators form. If I sound ignorant, that's because I am!

Comment: Actually, I managed to create a subform that shows principle investigators on a consortium, and allows you to add new ones, if they're already in the database. What's an effective way to add new principle investigators? What kind of forms can I use? I wish there was something at the end of the combo box that said "add new principle investigator..." that you could select, that would take you to a form to add one--much like how Gmail labels allow you to either select a label or add a new one.

Comment: You can choose limit to list for your combo and take advantage of not in list event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214329(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I generally use a small form, write the id to the form tag, hide the form and use the id from tag to update my combo.